# How use $scope.$apply on parent scope?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular 1.2, I have a child directive and a parent directive (with an isolate scope) to make a generic popup who takes directive in parameter and include it.

In my child directive i have to update the title of my parent directive, the value is updated in my console, but it is not updated in my UI.

Behavior:

1 - I set attributs of my directive declaration like : `

2 - I open my custom-box for audio devices by click on button -> the title equals A

3 - I have 3 tab in my audio-popup directive, so i click on 3rd tab, and i try to change the title of my custom-box -> FAIL

I ve tryed differents solutions but i can't find, i precise i can't use rootScope in this case.

```
//childDirective
$scope.setTabTo = function (to) {
    $scope.tab = to;
    if ($scope.tab == "already") {
       $scope.$parent.continueClose = false; //in console = false
       $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.$parent.title = "New Title" });
    }
    //...
};
```

I 've read this : [How to access parent scope from within a custom directive *with own scope* in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an)
but I have an error if i try $scope.$parent.$apply directly, have miss something to apply the scope ... 
And this post [Directive updates parent scope value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744046/directive-updates-parent-scope-value) doesn't works for me.

I have tryed to watch the title value in my parent directive but doesn't work to...

Comment: If child directive has no isolated scope, you should just $scope.Model.title = "New Title". You do not need apply. (Model.title cause just .title wont work - you can not change parent scope root objects, only nested ones)

Comment: You shouldn't need to `$apply` in this case.  Also, `if ($scope.tab = 'already')` will always return falsey.  You need `==` or better `===`.

Comment: @Petr Averyanov Thanks a lot, you have right that's the solution !!

Comment: did you try to use transculde ?? it gives you to control of your parent $scope.

Comment: yes, i've tried but in this case i 'm already in the good scope ^^ else i arrive in my rootscope and my variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If child directive has no isolated scope, you should just
>   $scope.Model.title = "New Title". You do not need apply. (Model.title
>   cause just .title wont work - you can not change parent scope root
>   objects, only nested ones) –  Petr Averyanov

True, i've just to use $scope.title and not $scope.$parent.title

in fact, my custom-box have an isolate scope but not my audio-popup directive so i can access directly my custom-box scope !

Answer (score 1):

The $parent you use is not the parent you think it is. Have in mind that the audio-popup may have isolated scope which will add another child in the chain. Also there are directives which create new child scopes: ng-controller, ng-switch, ng-if, ng-repeat, etc.

I also don't see why you need scope.$apply in this case. You need to call $apply only when you are modifying the scope from outside the angular world (e.g. element.on('click') instead of ng-click).

You have given us very little code to work with and to give you more exact answer.